# CSS Code That Will Not Work

Tags: html, css

Okay I'm trying to make a background that is hidden but will still show up just not on main content page, I want a other background for the main content itself, But it's just not working the main background is working fine just not the content background, Could anyone help me?

```
body {
    margin: 0px auto 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: #9fddf9 url(http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgfall.jpg) top center no-repeat fixed;
    width: 990px; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    font-family:  Tahoma;
    letter-spacing:1px; 
    line-height:15px; 
}   

#shell {
    margin: 0px auto 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    background: #91d8f4 url(http://unwritten-quotes.com/images/bg.gif) center repeat-y; 
    width: 990px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a container with id 'shell'?

Comment: can u put thi is in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Need your html as well!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aaNDC/

Comment: Just added that as well on jsfiddle

Comment: See what i'm talking about, the background doesn't show up on the content...I'm so lost...ehh.

Comment: You should add some html for the shell

Comment: There's nothing with an id of '"shell" in your fiddle. The actual fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/aaNDC/2/ by the way, and it has a LOT of content, but nothing called "shell".

Comment: @Travis Reed don't forget to give height, people may forget

Comment: Thank you guys, I've got it fixed. I was missing a few things, When i brought over all my old content and css/etc to my new site. Everything is working fine now and i will @Deekey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give height for `#shell {height:500px}`

here you can see the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/7jW8y/14/

Answer (score 1):

Have you added any content to `#shell`? If you haven't defined any height to your div and/or it  doesn't have any content, then it will not show..

```
<style>
body {margin: 0px auto 0px; padding: 0px;overflow-x:hidden;background: #9fddf9 url(http://www.unwritten-quotes.com/images/bgfall.jpg) top center no-repeat fixed;width: 990px; color: #000000; font-size: 11px; font-family:  Tahoma;letter-spacing:1px; line-height:15px; }    
#shell {margin: 0px auto 0px; padding: 0px;background: #91d8f4 url(http://unwritten-quotes.com/images/bg.gif) center repeat-y; width: 990px;}

</style>
<body>

<div id="shell">CONTENT</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or add `height:100px;/*or what ever hight you want*/` to your `#shell`